# How do I dynamically change the z-index of a photo?

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I want to change the `z-index` of an image in a grouping of photos that I am absolutely positioning in a body element. I would like it so that when I roll over an image it increases in size using the web-kit transform in CSS.

The problem is that images higher in order in my HTML file stack over the top of images lower. I would like to have a script that increases the `z-index` of a file so that when I roll over it it does not appear behind a neighboring photo.

I have spent some time looking for `z-index` addition files as in my head you just keep increasing the `z-index` into into infinity incrementally with a jquery file but i dont know how to code that.

Essentially I want a grouping of photos close to each other to not overlap each other when they increase in size.

Is that feasible?

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Comment: CSS Transforms will have an impact on z-index, as positioning do. See http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2435279

Answer (score 2):

With CSS something like:

```
.photo_group .photo:hover {
    z-index: 1000; /* May depend on over indices defined! */
}
```

Please post some HTML if you need exact CSS ruls / class names. This is only a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
  <style>
  img{
      position:absolute;
  }
  img.apple{
      top: 40px;
      left: 0px;
  }
  img.ipod{
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
  }
  img.thanks{
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseZIndex(obj){
    obj.style.zIndex = 1;
}
function decreaseZIndex(obj){
    obj.style.zIndex = 0;
}
</script>
<img src='http://images.apple.com/home/images/billboard_25b_thankyou_headline_Yr4p8DedLk7y.png' onmouseover='increaseZIndex(this);' onmouseout='decreaseZIndex(this);' class='thankyou'/>
<img src='http://edibleapple.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/silver-apple-logo.png' onmouseover='increaseZIndex(this);' onmouseout='decreaseZIndex(this);' class='apple'/>
<img src='http://www.ipod.org.uk/ipod_nano.jpg' onmouseover='increaseZIndex(this);' onmouseout='decreaseZIndex(this);' class='ipod' />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[See it in action on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqGwW/1/)